# How to call WCF service in the FitNesse test?

Tags: c#, wcf, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim

I'm trying to call WCF service in the FitNesse test.
When I'm trying to initialize a client with the following code:

```
    using (var client = new Status.StatusSoapClient())
    {
        client.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(url);
        response = client.GetProductionTicketStatus(dealerId, orderId, orderLineId);

    }
```

I get an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find default endpoint
>   element that references contract 'Status.StatusSoap' in the
>   ServiceModel client configuration section.

which makes sense because .NET Framework does not support configuration for DLLs.

MSDN Library says: "You have to move your configuration code into the configuration file recognized by your hosting environment". But I'm not sure if this is possible to be done for FitNesse.

So I tried to create binding myself without trying to read it from config

```
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100000);
    binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100000);
    binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10000;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 10000;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 10000;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 10000;
    var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(url);
    var myClient = new Status.StatusSoapClient(binding, endpoint);
    response = myClient.GetProductionTicketStatus(dealerId, orderId, orderLineId);
```

But when I try to run the test with this code I get the "Testing was interrupted and results are incomplete." error on FitNesse.

This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/646177/2211481 suggests to make a copy of the app.config for the testrunner. When I copy my app.config to Runner.exe.config, put it to the Runner folder and run the initial code again I get the "Testing was interrupted and results are incomplete." error on FitNesse again.

Is there a way I could solve this?

Comment: Something is failing in your test when you get 'testing was interrupted...'  You'll need to debug and find the cause.  This may help: http://www.asoftwarecraft.com/2010/01/troubleshooting-with-fitsharp-and.html

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by defining COMMAND_PATTERN as described here: http://twenty6-jc.blogspot.nl/2010/07/wcf-and-fitnesse-how-to-load-clients.html

> !define COMMAND_PATTERN {%m -a
>   c:\projects\someapplication\acceptancetests\acceptancetests.dll.config
>   -r fitSharp.Slim.Service.Runner,c:\tools\nslim\fitsharp.dll %p}

Making a copy of the app.config for the testrunner also worked in the end.

I was getting "Testing was interrupted and results are incomplete." error because of a mistake in my code which I solved after debugging.

Answer (score 0):

See this post: [FitNesse App.Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849172/fitnesse-app-config/27625279#27625279)

[NetRunner](https://github.com/imanushin/NetRunner) uses configuration file for the first dll from the list.

For exampple, for the line:

```
!path C:\Probjects\HelloWorld\bin\Debug\FitNesseHelloWorld1.dll, C:\Probjects\HelloWorld\bin\Debug\FitNesseHelloWorld2.dll
```

NetRunner will use configuration file "C:\Probjects\HelloWorld\bin\Debug\FitNesseHelloWorld1.dll.config"